# Error while installing heroku toolbelt on Windows 8: Unable to execute file C:\Program Files(x86)\Heroku\ruby-1.9.3\bin\gem.bat

Tags: ruby, heroku, windows-8, ruby-1.9.3, heroku-toolbelt

I wanted to install heroku toolbelt. I choose full instalation.

While install I got this error.

[image]

After install finishes `heroku login` does not work.

Comment: what is the ruby version that you have installed on windows 8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754758/problems-downloading-heroku-toolbelt-on-vista-machine (removed, but scraped here: http://www.techques.com/question/1-9754758/Problems-downloading-Heroku-toolbelt-on-Vista-machine)

Answer (score 1):

try this out:

[Follow this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-gaming/error-shellexecuteex-failedcode-2-when-installing/17b5c287-da94-44ba-8b41-8ffba76ba9af?tab=question&status=AllReplies#tabs) No matter it is related to running game on windows 7, try this on your windows 8. and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

try running it again as an administrator by right clicking on the file

Comment: have given a try. not working. Something else. Seems that something 8.0 specifics because with 8.1 it works...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the permission to write a file to the partition. You can try to run the installer with Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Windows 8 X64 VM on my mac and i just installed Heroku tool belt on it and it seems to run without any issues.

[image]

Either try restarting your system or running gem.bat individually to see if it works or not.Possibly unprivileged to run with the current user account.